# Sunspot, solr indexing belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I am trying to set search on a model that has a lot of different associations. I am starting with the belongs_to associations. I am able to search on the name field of the Product model successfully but the when I perform a search on what would be in the associated models I just get the default results.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#Product Model
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  searchable do
    text :name

    integer :store_id, :references => Store.name

    text :store do
      Store.all.map { |store| store.name }
    end
  end
end 


#product controler
def search 
    @search = Sunspot.search(Product) do
      fulltext params[:search] do
        fields(:name, :store)
      end
    end

    @products = @search.results
end

#Store Model
searchable do
  text :name
end
```

Comment: Itemdesign? Why? Why not Sunspot.search(Product) or Product.search?

Comment: Sorry about that. It's actually Product. I edited it

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store

    searchable do
        text :name
        index :store do
            index :name
        end
        integer :store_id # do you really need this? I think not.
    end
end
```

Don't forget to reindex after each change in your models.

**EDIT**: You don't need to index the Store class by itself, unless you plan to search on it.

Comment: Would I do that within the Product Class?

Comment: Yes. All you need to do is change the one line where you map the values. You are assigning the entire Stores table to each product... This is wrong. product has_many :stores, not all of them...

Comment: OK, when I do that and reindex I get a long error in the console. Somewhere in there it says NoMethodError: undefined method `stores' for #<Class:0x007f9bcd785f08>. This is confusing because there definitely is a belongs_to association with :store

Comment: Sorry, wait, what are your relations? product has_many :stores, or product belongs_to :store?

Comment: product belongs_to store

Comment: Then my answer is wrong and I need to edit it. Wait one moment and check it.

Comment: OK, I get NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when I do that.

Comment: Ok.. Try my last edited suggestion and after that I will give up and remove the comment if it doesn't work... Sorry for troubling you...

Comment: nevermind there are couple of empty store fields in the db. Thanks for your help

Comment: First of all no trouble at all! I totally appreciate the help. However, the last edit didn't work. It gave a long error again. I think my problem lies in the nil objects. I need to figure out how to deal with that now

Comment: Ok, Have a look at this though: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Sunspot-2.0-README